# Sudoku checker algorithm in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, sudoku

I'm currently working on an algorithm to find all numbers with 9 digits using numbers 1-9 without any repeats. I'm testing a theory I have that filtering numbers as such will make for a more efficient sudoku checker.

The code that I implemented does the following. It uses a for loop for places 1-9 in a number, such that (a)(b)(c)(d)(e)(f)(g)(h)(i) = #########.

My theory is that by checking if the sum of the numbers (a-i) is equal to 45, that the product of a through i is equal to 9! and that the sum of the inverses of a-i is equal to roughly 2.828968 (or 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 ... 1/9)

The issue is that after I filter the 9-digit numbers by the sum of the inverses of a-i, the count of possible 9-digit numbers predicted is less than 9! (the actual amount of possible numbers). I'm not sure why it's filtering so much, but the numbers that it does catch do not have any repeats (which is good).

My thoughts are that the way I am playing with doubles is messing up the algorithm.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int product;
    int sum;
    int count=0;
    double inverseSum;
    double correctInverseSum=(1.0/1.0)+(1.0/2.0)+(1.0/3.0)+(1.0/4.0)+(1.0/5.0)+
(1.0/6.0)+(1.0/7.0)+(1.0/8.0)+(1.0/9.0);
        for(double a=1.0; a<10.0; a++){
            for(double b=1.0; b<10.0; b++){
                for(double c=1.0; c<10.0; c++){
                for(double d=1.0; d<10.0; d++){
                    for(double e=1.0; e<10.0; e++){
                        for(double f=1.0; f<10.0; f++){
                            for(double g=1.0; g<10.0; g++){
                                for(double h=1.0; h<10.0; h++){
                                    for(double i=1.0; i<10.0; i++){
                                        product=a*b*c*d*e*f*g*h*i;
                                        sum=a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i;
                                        if(product==9*8*7*6*5*4*3*2*1 && sum==45){
                                            inverseSum=(1.0/a)+(1.0/b)+(1.0/c)+(1.0/d)+
                                            (1.0/e)+(1.0/f)+(1.0/g)+(1.0/h)+(1.0/i);
                                            if(inverseSum==correctInverseSum)
                                            {
                                                count++;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<"This is the count:"<<count<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I haven't seen so many nested for-loops in my entire life!

Comment: What is your question? And @PaulManta is right, the code is scary :D

Comment: Haha yeah I know it's awful, I am testing a theory I have. This code won't actually be implemented into my sudoku checker.

My question is why is it giving me only 112112 results after filtering the 9-digit numbers instead of 9! (362880) theoretical possibilities of 9-digit numbers with no repeats.

Comment: It's terrible practice to use floating-point values as loop counters - they're slow and they have precision issues. Also, I mean no offense, but your code generally looks terribly complicated and you'll have a hard time changing it if you keep it this way.

Answer (score 2):

Now that I washed my eyes after seeing so many for loops, I'd say a candidate is:

```
if(inverseSum==correctInverseSum)
```

`double`s aren't exactly representable, so you'll have to check for equality using a small epsilon. Something like:

```
if (fabs(inverseSum - correctInverseSum) < std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon())
```

You'll need to `#include <limits>`.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need some error tolerance in your checking:

```
if(fabs(inverseSum-correctInverseSum) < 1e-6) count++
```

Alternatively, multiply through by 9!, you get

```
b*c*d*e*f*g*h*i + a*c*d*e*f*g*h*i ...
```

(one missing factor in each term the sum).  Then you can use integer arithmetic instead of floats.

Comment: How about `std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()`?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore  It isn't straightforward to use that, as there are multiple roundings so it may be out by multiples of epsilon.  That said, you could compute correctInverseSum 9! different ways, it would have to be == to one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Let's run a quick experiment: Let's try to compute the inverse sum from big to small and in reverse order:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

struct generator
{
    generator(): d_value() {}
    double operator()() { return 1.0 / ++this->d_value; }
    double d_value;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> values;
    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(values), 9, generator());
    double ordered(std::accumulate(values.begin(), values.end(), 0.0));
    double reversed(std::accumulate(values.rbegin(), values.rend(), 0.0));
    std::cout << "ordered=" << ordered << " "
              << "reversed=" << reversed << " "
              << "difference=" << (reversed - ordered) << " "
              << "\n";
}
```

If this where exact math, clearly this should yield the same sum. After all, they are the same set of values. Unfortunately, it turns out that the values are not exactly the same. Here is the output it shows for me:

```
ordered=2.82897 reversed=2.82897 difference=4.44089e-16
```

The problem is that the values are not exact and adding two of these non-exact values introduces some error. Often the error doesn't matter too much but trying to compare the results for identity won't work: depending on the order of the operations different operands with different rounded results are involved.

Answer (score 0):

An old adage, but please: Don't repeat yourself.

Keep it DRY.

When you find yourself writing this kind of code you should ask yourself why Do I need to repeat myself in this way.

There are plenty of other options.

1 - recursion. get yourself comfortable with the concept.

2 - the mod operator   for i = 0 to 100    r = i % 10,    c = i / 10

3 - reevaluating the problem. You are trying to solve a problem that is harder than necessary

Answer (score 0):

Haven't you heard about std::bitset? You only need nine bits to verify, which is probably within your budget.

I've been meaning to get some practice with variadic templates, so I wrote this for you: (c++11 experts, feel free to rip it to pieces.)

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>

template<unsigned long i>
bool test_helper(std::bitset<i> seen) {
  return seen.count() == i;
}

template<unsigned long i, typename T, typename... Args>
bool test_helper(std::bitset<i> seen, T arg1, Args... args) {
  return test_helper(seen.set(arg1 - 1), args...);
}

template<typename... Args>
bool test(Args... args) {
  return test_helper(std::bitset<sizeof... (Args)>(), args...);
}

template<unsigned long size, bool done = false>
struct Counter {
  template<typename ... Args>
  unsigned long operator()(Args... args) {
    unsigned long count = 0;
    for (int a = 1; a < 10; ++a)
      count += Counter<size, size == sizeof...(Args)+1>()(a, args...);
    return count;
  }
};

template<unsigned long i>
struct Counter<i, true> {
  template<typename ... Args>
  unsigned long operator()(Args... args) {
    return test(args...);
  }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  std::cout << Counter<9>()() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

If you really insist on using complicated and heuristics, you could also get some experience with rational arithmetic to compute your inverse sum. It should be clear sum of 1/a<sub>i</sub> is Σ<sub>j</sub> (Π<sub>i</sub> a<sub>i</sub>)/a<sub>j</sub> all divided by Π<sub>i</sub> a<sub>i</sub>; you're already computing the denominator, so it only is necessary to compute the numerator, whose maximum value is 9<sup>9</sup>. But, still, the bitset solution seems a lot simpler to me.